# Is it possible to make hair particles avoid each other?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, particles

I have a scene in which I have two Hair type particle systems. I am having an issue with them intersecting each other, even with different seed values. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Also, would using the Emitter particle type make any difference? Also, can this be done with a script?

[image: Particle Intersect Issue]

More screenshots available as requested.

Comment: soon with hair dynamics, devs are working on it. You can try to comb your particles if not too many.

Answer (score 2):

as you need hairs, using emitter type is not a good idea. try to use 2 different particle systems : 1 for the grass, another for the flowers. Use a vertex group at least for one of them to control where your particles will pop.

you can also use translucency in your materials (petals and grass) to make it less visible.

Or edit the flower particle system (less flowers than grass), uncheck the keep root option to be allowed to move the entire hair.
[image]

move the hairs with comb brush and place them where you need, or cut where you don't want them, add where you want some

[image]

Comment: I am already using two particle systems, the cause of the issue. The seed is different as well :/

Comment: Can't control density with vertex group?

Comment: The density doesn't control the actual particle position, the faces are emitting the hair particles.

Comment: Translucency is not a solution :/ I need the actual geometries to not intersect each other.

Comment: what i did was making flowers higher than grass :)

Comment: That is an option, but I do really like it at the height it  is at . . .

Comment: as there might be less flowers, edit manually (move or add/remove) your flower particle system to make them pop where you want

Comment: uncheck keep/root to move them.

Comment: Although this is not perfect (has to be done manually) this will work. Thanks!

Comment: One day we will be used to say : particles did exactly what I expected...but not today :)